# Leads only convert when an opportunity already exists

Tags: lead-conversion, nonprofit-starter-pack

I'm using NPSP.

If I create an opportunity, then convert a Lead and use that already existing opportunity, it will convert just fine.

If, however, I try to have the opportunity created during the Lead conversion process, I get the error "There was an error converting the lead. Please try again. If the problem persists, please contact your administrator".

I've removed all opportunity field mappings, so there wouldn't be an outdated package field in there.

The debug logs, the only suspicious thing I can see is something in the NPSP namespace `"Number of SOQL queries: 101 out of 100 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT".`

I have no flows or process builders running on opportunity creation.

Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: NPSP does have trigger logic, so it sounds like something might be happening with the way your org is configured that's not immediately obvious.

Comment: You should open a case with Salesforce and be sure to specify NPSP or Nonprofit Industry as the category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wound up being governor limits being hit by my own processes. The debug logs shows the NPSP namespace, but the SOQL queries were all in-house triggers and flows.